# How to get the user organization from using web service client in java?

Tags: java, web-services, liferay

> My code
>
> I have been trying to get the organization that the liferay user has, but it is not able to get the user organization using userId. I get Axis fault, the url works fine.

```
public class WStest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inside the client program!!");
        try {

            OrganizationServiceSoapServiceLocator locator = new OrganizationServiceSoapServiceLocator();
            OrganizationServiceSoap soap = locator
                    .getPortal_OrganizationService(_getURL("Portal_OrganizationService"));

            OrganizationSoap[] organizations = soap
                    .getUserOrganizations(20198l);
            for (int i = 0; i < organizations.length; i++) {
                OrganizationSoap organization = organizations[i];
                System.out.println(organization.getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static URL _getURL(String serviceName) throws Exception {
        String remoteUser = "20198";
        String password = "test";
        String url = "http://" + remoteUser + ":" + password    + "@localhost:8080/api/secure/axis/" + serviceName;
        return new URL(url);
    }

}
```

> The error I get is this.

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (404)Not Found
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {}:return code:  404

(404)Not Found
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.http.Portal_OrganizationServiceSoapBindingStub.getUserOrganizations(Portal_OrganizationServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1156)
    at com.mywebservices.WStest1.main(WStest1.java:22)
```

Comment: 404 simply refers to incorrect location,mostly due to some missing params or missing in url .Try out the URL first from browser or using Postman chrome plugin to verify,it''s not with the code but with the URL

Comment: The url I use is taking me to default liferay page, and in console I get warning like "code="404", msg="/api/secure/axis/Portal_OrganizationService", uri=/api/secure/axis/Portal_OrganizationService}"

Comment: Did you try with the liferay web service console for the validity of the url??Reference link:https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/invoking-json-web-services

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the url

```
http://20198:test@localhost:8080/api/secure/axis/Portal_OrganizationService
```

is not found. Try that url into your browser first.

Comment: The id should come first and password it is 20198:test, I check and link is taking me to my default liferay page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not in the position to help you now. BTW, my answer is correct :)

Comment: You don't give any hint about your Liferay version number - I'm not sure if the location/implementation changed because I'm not using the SOAP services. A quick look at a WSDL that I had at hand reveals that there's no 'secure' declared in the path.